# spring delay/pause @Scheduled in integration tests until trigger

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have several `@Scheduled` tasks in our project. In integration tests they throw an exception, because tables cannot be found - which is true, because the integrtion tests clean + set up a database only in `@BeforeEach` when spring already was started.

We now workaround this issue by using `initialDelayString` to set a delay if the `test` profile is active:

```
@Scheduled(
    initialDelayString = "\${scheduler.initialDelay}",
    fixedDelay = DELAY_BETWEEN_SCHEDULES
  )
```

However, this is buggy, because we cannot guarantee how long it takes to setup the schema. Setting the initialDelay to e.g. 20 seconds feels very odd.

Is there any way to delay the initial run of `@Scheduled` until a trigger is set (e.g. db schema created, initial data loaded etc)? And is it possible to stop the schedulers in between tests to wait again for that trigger?

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with it, you can actually suppress the cron job run altogether.
All you have to do is a the class with cron job as @MockBean in the test call. something like.. In this case it won't run the cron job at all as part of integration test

```
class MyTest {

    @MockBean
     ClassWithCronJob dummyJob;

}
```